# how can i open the response of a post request that sent with request lib, in a browser and have exact same page content with same cookies and session

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python-requests, http-post, httpresponse

When I send a post request by `request.post()` the response is an html content that I want to see it and interact with web page, just like when I click a button and the browser redirects me to that page. I.e. I have just changed the place of --click-- with --direct request-- but I want to open the same page.

When I tried to manually open that address and replace cookies with request response cookies, this method did not work and server didn't recognize me.